# Explain this fragment of Javascript to me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to jQuery, 
can someone explain what this code does:

```
$("#currency form").submit(function(e) {

        triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();
        return e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first line begins a function that handles the `submit` event of all `form` tag(s) in the element with ID `currency`.
*Documentation*: [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [`submit` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

The second line closes an overlay in the second element in the `triggers` variable.
*Documentation*: [`eq` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [overlay plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay.html)

The third line tries to prevent the submit, but isn't completely correct.  (It should be `e.preventDefault();` and/or `return false;`)
*Documentation*: [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-object)

Comment: +1 for correctness, without the "return false;" it might get submitted anyway

Comment: @Alex: Wrong. `e.preventDefault()` _will_ prevent the submission, even without `return false`.

Comment: Fair enough, I still always add return false anyway! :P

Answer (score 2):

`triggers` = a jQuery object

`triggers.eq(1)` = get the second element from the matched elements inside the jquery object

`triggers.eq(1).overlay()` = get the overlay instance (a plugin) on the second element

`triggers.eq(1).overlay().close()` = close the overlay.

`return e.preventDefault()`; = prevent the default action (form submission)

Answer (score 2):

On the submit event of the form, it will:

1. Get the second element in the triggers collection (of jQuery elements).
2. Get the overlay on that element.
3. Close that overlay.
4. Prevent the submit event from bubbling to the parent handler.